# Python LXML code doesn't obtain visible text

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I'm scraping some info from a website, but LXML doesn't seem to obtain the text **although the same code worked before.**
I'm using LXML and requests.

```py
    url = f"https://fauxid.com/fake-name-generator/croatia?age=18-24&gender={gender}"
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    name = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/text()")[0].strip()
    first_name, last_name = name.split()
```

The XPATH of the name is `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span`.

The error that occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\asdfasdf.py", line 25, in <module>
    name = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/text()")[0].strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

There were no errors a few days ago and just now it seems that it doesn't work.
When running the code it seems that the website isn't even being opened as my supposedly generated persona isn't on their website [here](https://fauxid.com/recent-identities).
Also, the same error message is on any other element I'm scraping.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The only reason I'm grabbing this data is because I need to create personas for my database for a school project.

Comment: If you check the resulting HTML, it's a warning saying you need to enable javascript to use the site, then there is a cloudfare captcha. Have you seen the faker module? Perhaps that can work for you: https://pypi.org/project/Faker/